# MVP win forms application

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net, dependency-injection, mvp

In a module of a win forms application I have a hierarchy of classes like `BaseRecovery`, `LoanRecovery` and `FineRecovery`. Both `LoanRecovery` and `FineRecovery` inherits from `BaseRecovery`. All these models have one view called `RecoveryForm` where you can enter/view loans and fines of employees. and I'm planing to use single Presenter class called `RecoveryPresenter` which inherits from `BasePresenter`. We have a `DataService` Class for db transactions

LoanRecovery class looks like this...

```
Class LoanRecovery : BaseRecovery
{
    public string LoanID {get;set;}
    public DateTime IssueDate {get;set;}
    public Decimal Amount {get;set;}
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So I'd do the following in Programe.cs.

```
IBaseRcovery recovery=null;
IRecoveryForm recoveryForm = new RecoveryForm();
IDataService dataService = new DataService();

BasePresenter presenter = new RecoveryPresenter( recovery, recoveryForm, dataService );
presenter.Show(); // This will display the form recoveryForm
```

In the presenter I would say

```
public RecoveryPresenter( IBaseRecover model, IRecoveryForm view, IDataService dataService )
{
    this._Model = model;
    this._View = view;
    this._DataService = dataService;            
    WireUpViewEvents();

}
```

Now lets say if I need to give a loan, I would run `SetModelPropertisFromView()` method in the `BasePresenter` class which use reflection. But before that I should pass an instance of `LoanRecovery` class (i.e. _Model) to that method together with `_View`. Like wise we can do same thing for all children classes as follows...

```
    public void Issue()
    {
        if (_View.Type == "Loan")
        {
            _Model = new LoanRecovery();
            SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View, _DataService);
            _dataService.InsertLoan(_Model); //Error
        }

        if (_View.Type == "Fine")
        {
            _Model = new FineRecovery();
            SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View, _DataService);
            _DataService.InsertFine(_Model); //Error
        }

        if (_View.Type == "Insurance")
        {
            _Model = new InsuranceRecovery();
            SetModelPropertiesFromView(_Model, _View, _DataService);
            _DataService.InsertFine(_Model); //Error
        }


    }
```

Everything is fine until the last line of the above if blocks. The issue is the data access method in the `DataService` class requires a child instance not a base class instance.

```
  public void InsertLoan( LoanRecovery loan)
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(db.GetConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("BEGIN INSERT INTO recovery ;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@empID", SqlDbType.Char).Value = loan.EmployeeID;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@loanType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loan.Type;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@loanAmount", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = loan.FullAmount;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@loanDuration", SqlDbType.Int).Value = loan.Duration;
            sqlConnection.Open();
            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

So I solved the problem like this

```
    public void Issue()
    {
        if (_View.Type == "Loan")
        {
            LoanRecovery loanModel = new LoanRecovery(); //Creates a child instance
            SetModelPropertiesFromView(loanModel, _View, _DataService);
            _DataService.InsertLoan(loanModel);
        }
    }
```

Now it's working but my worry is that I'm not using the injected instance through the constructor rather `newing` a child object which creates a dependency. Can anybody propose a better design to solve this issue please?

Comment: What do `IBaseRecover` and `BaseRecovery` look like?  It seems rather confusing that you need different types (i.e., `LoanRecovery`, `FineRecovery`, and `InsuranceRecovery`) if `IBaseRecover` has all the properties necessary to represent the underlying data, as suggested by the fact that you use `IBaseRecover` for your model.

Comment: Actually 'BaseRecovery' class has only the common properties and 'FineRecovery' has property 'Reason' and InsuranceRecovery has property 'PolicyID' and LoanRecovery has property 'Guaranty'. IBaseRecovery is just an interface only.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of typos in your code blocks, that lead me to believe the code wasn't taken from the working code in your IDE. I will assume the following:

- `IBaseRcovery` is really `IBaseRecovery`
- `RecoveryPresenter( IBaseRecover model, ...` is really `RecoveryPresenter(IBaseRecovery model, ...`
- `SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("BEGIN INSERT INTO recovery ;` is really `SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("BEGIN INSERT INTO recovery ...");`

That said, the naming feels awkward with an underscore followed by a capital letter:

> ```
> this._Model = model;
> this._View = view;
> this._DataService = dataService;
> ```

I would rather see this:

```
_model = model;
_view = view;
_dataService = dataService;
```

Or that:

```
this.model = model;
this.view = view;
this.dataService = dataService;
```

But not a mixture of both.

The *raison d'être* of the underscore prefix is to avoid having to use the `this` qualifier; if you prefix a field name with an underscore *and* use `this`, you're cluttering up your code.

Also convention is `camelCase` (i.e. lowercase first letter) for private fields, local variables and parameters. `PascalCase` (i.e. uppercase first letter) is for type and member names (classes, interfaces, delegates, enums, events, methods, etc.).

---

You can declare a variable without initializing it. When it's a *reference type*, it's set to `null` until you assign it a reference. Hence, this is perfectly redundant:

> ```
> IBaseRecovery recovery = null;
> ```

You could just do this:

```
IBaseRecovery recovery;
```

---

Looks like *generics* could come in handy here:

> ```
> public RecoveryPresenter(IBaseRecovery model, IRecoveryForm view, IDataService dataService)
> ```

Can turn into a constructor for a generic class:

```
public class Presenter<TView, TModel> 
    where TView : IView
    where TModel : class
{
    private TModel _model;
    private TView _view;
    private IRepository<TModel> _repository;

    public Presenter(TModel model, TView view, IRepository<TModel> repository)
    {
        _model = model;
        _view = view;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

If `IBaseRecovery` is only a *marker interface* with no members, get rid of it, it smells.

The key here, is `IRepository<TModel>`: your `DataService` has too many responsibilities, its interface will keep getting modified as you add more features to your application (i.e. as you need to deal with more database tables), and that's not very cleanly extensible.

The `IRepository<TModel>` interface could look something like this:

```
public interface IRepository<TModel> where TModel : class
{
    void SelectAll();
    void GetById(int id);
    void Insert(TModel model);
    void Update(TModel model);
    void Delete(TModel model);
}
```

Look into the *repository pattern* for more information. The idea is that you'll have a family of specialized classes, all presenting the same interface, that perform similar operations on different parts of the underlying database:

```
public class LoanRepository : IRepository<Loan>

public class FineRepository : IRepository<Fine>

...
```

You can even derive all these classes from an abstract `ReposityBase` class (non-generic), and implement the common code only once (i.e. connection set-up & disposal, for example).

Now, if your presenter is going to be dealing with more than a single database table / repository, you have a problem; that problem is solved with a *unit of work*, which the presenter can depend on:

```
public class Presenter<TView> 
    where TView : IView
{
    private IUnifOfWork _uow;
    private TView _view;

    public Presenter(IUnitOfWork uow, TView view)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _view = view;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

*Repository* and *Unit-of-Work* patterns usually go hand-in-hand; [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60820/23788) is an example of an implementation I've written in VBA recently. It's another language and an earlier data access technology, but you'll find many similarities - look at the *pattern*, not the code itself.

And/or read up on *repository+UoW* design patterns; adding these to your arsenal should greatly simplify your life.